# how do i click a hyperlink on a webpage using java without having the page open in browser

Tags: java, html, hyperlink

**so im trying to make a file downloader that will download files based on what a hyperlink says or is called how would i go about clicking a hyperlink in java?**

im trying to find the easiest way to do this with out opening a webpage.

*also im trying to do this with no java script because i do not control the site i only want to download from it.*

this is something i have been trying but i keep getting ERROR 403. how do i fix this?

NOTE: *this does use the JSoup library.*

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(yourURLhere), 2000);

    Elements resultLinks = doc.select("a");
    System.out.println("number of links: " + resultLinks.size());
    for (Element link1 : resultLinks) {
        System.out.println();
        String href = link1.attr("href");
        System.out.println("Title: " + link1.text());
        System.out.println("Url: " + href);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jSoup library is an HTML parser/scraper, but it does not interact with a webpage. If you want to click on a link or otherwise interact with webpages, you will need to use a library that simulates a web browser, such as [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

For example, the following code would click the "Home" link on the HTMLUnit homepage. This code searches for a specific anchor (HTML link) according to the `name` attribute, but there are other methods which search for other types of elements by various criteria. See the documentation for more details.

```
public void testHomePage() throws Exception { 
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
    final URL url = new URL("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net"); 

    final HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(url); 

    HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByName("Home"); 
    anchor.click();
}
```

You can still use HTMLUnit in conjunction with jSoup, if you want to use jSoup's analysis features. After loading a page in HTMLUnit, you can pass the HTML as a string to jSoup's `parse()` method.

Comment: for some reason the "HTMLAnchor" in "HTMLAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByName("Home");" is getting an error cannot find symbol. 

what should i do?

Comment: i don't have a java setup on this computer, but it's probably an import issue. have you imported `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor`?

Comment: ok now it works it was the caps on HTMLAnchor the HTML did not need them. but there is now an error